# Why is the velocity of a particle undergoing simple harmonic motion always positive according to this formula?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

We know that the velocity of a particle undergoing simple harmonic motion, $v$, is given by-

$$v=A\omega\cos(\omega t+\delta)...(i)$$

Now, depending on the phase $(\omega t+\delta)$, the value of $v$ can be either positive or negative. Now, there is another relation; that relation is between velocity and displacement:

$$v=\omega A\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\omega t+\delta)}$$

$$\implies v=\omega A\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{A^2}}$$

$$\implies v=\omega A\sqrt{\frac{A^2-x^2}{A^2}}$$

$$\implies v=\omega\sqrt{A^2-x^2}...(ii)$$

Here, we can see that v is always positive as $\omega$ and $\sqrt{A^2-x^2}$ is always positive, but we saw from (i) that $v$ can be both positive and negative. So, how can we reconcile between (i) and (ii)?

Comment: Second equation should actually be $v=±\omega \sqrt{A^2 - x^2}$ , as $\cos (\omega t + \delta)$ can be + or - , $\sqrt{1-\sin^2 (\omega t + \delta)}$ can be ± too.

Comment: @ACB Yes. Well, squaring the equation is a big no-no as the solution to the squared equation includes the solution to our original equation along with extra information. $$\cos\theta=\cos\theta...(i)$$
$$\cos^2\theta=1-\sin^2\theta$$
$$\cos\theta=\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}...(ii)$$

Solution to (ii) contains the solution to (i) along with extra information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How?

Don't take square roots.

Plotting the two solutions, cosine in blue, and square root in orange:

[image]

shows you are throwing out phase information with the square root...well, actually when you square the position. When $x\rightarrow x^2$, you can no longer distinguish between the positive and negative phases of the oscillation.